# Making fields mandatory of a specific sheet on workbook save

Tags: excel, vba

I am using macros in excel to make fields mandatory in excel workbook. However, the problem is that the workbook contains multiple worksheets and the macro applies to all the worksheets.

Is there a way to target a specific worksheet in the workbook?

Below is the code i am using:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
If Cells(5, 2).Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please fill cell B5"
    Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
  For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count 
   If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name = "Name of specific sheet" Then
     If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Cells(5, 2).Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please fill cell B5"
        Cancel = True
     End If
   End If
  Next i
End Sub
```

Where the **"Name of specific sheet"** is the worksheet name that you validate `Cells(5, 2).Value = ""` for.

Comment: Works but is overkill to look at every sheet for a match rather than directly on the chosen sheet.

Comment: Thank you KaushalKapoor - I'm glad it helped you, but please consider also the answers by GeneSkuratovsky and @brettdj since they are - as far as I see - more efficient and might be better for solving your problem - so my answer might not deserve applying as "answer to the problem", even though it was written first (as far as I know "apply" choice changing is possible if you decided to). Nevertheless - thanks and wish you all the best :)

Comment: Thanks T_G for the comments but if your code worked for the OP to their satisfaction then I'm happy it's their call :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim shX As Worksheet
    Dim rX As Range

    Set shX = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set rX = shX.Cells(5, 2)
    If rX = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please fill cell B5"
        Cancel = True
        shX.Select
        rX.Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

More directly

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Your sheet name here")
If Len(ws.[b5]) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Please fill cell B5 on sheet " & ws.Name, vbCritical, "File not saved"
    Cancel = True
    Application.Goto ws.[b5]
End If
End Sub
```